# save a different value in the redux store than what is displayed on the frontend

Tags: react-redux, react-redux-form

I'm wondering if I can store a different value in the redux form FieldArray than what's displayed on the frontend.

Using the example from the [docs](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/): Each `club` has a club name and consists out of various `members`. I want to introduce another model called `group` which also consists out of at least one `member`.

I combine the `firstName` and `lastName` field to one field and let the user type in either the members individually OR the user can type in a group name which then fills in all members of that group but on the frontend, only the group name shows up, instead of each member name individually.

Currently, I allow this and then before I post the values to the server, I fetch the members of that group via a get request and then switch the group name for the member names.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant (and faster) way to do this? I was looking at the [parse](https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/docs/api/fields.md/#-code-parse-value-name-gt-parsedvalue-code-optional-) method but it changes the value right away and doesn't let me display it how the user typed it in.